# Restrictive vs Non-restrictive Relative Clause

Tags: relative-clauses, non-restrictive

Can you tell me the difference in the meaning of the two sentences below?

As a defining relative clause.

> The location which was called Central Park was a park in New York.

As a non-defining relative clause.

> The location, which was called Central Park, was a park in New York.

Comment: Perhaps it would help to imagine a suitable sentence preceding each of the two examples you've provided: (1) "The NSA guy stopped at a series of locations which had vaguely familiar names. The location which was called Central Park was a park in New York." (2) "The NSA guy dropped off the vice president in a secure, previously undisclosed location.  The location, which was called Central Park, was a park in New York." Do you see how the two opening sentences lead to the two differently punctuated forms of the example sentence that you ask about?

Comment: Related question, [Should this be a restrictive or non-restrictive relative clause?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/283762/should-this-be-a-restrictive-or-non-restrictive-relative-clause) and [Does removing the comma before 'which' in a non-restrictive clause change the meaning of the sentence?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/182769/does-removing-the-comma-before-which-in-a-non-restrictive-clause-change-the-me).

Comment: Can you really call a*location* a *park*? This seems imprecise; instead, *Central Park was a park located in New York*; or *This was the location of a New York park known as Central Park.*; or, less awkwardly, *This was the location in New York of Central Park.* (it being understood that a place with *Park* in the name is probably a park).

Answer (score 1):

The non-restricting version gives extra information about the location (it was called Central Park).  The restricting version helps you find your memory of the location (the location **that** was called Central Park).  The preferred methods are to use 'that' to restrict, and to use ', which' to give extra (adverbial) info.

Answer (score 1):

The reference of C (the places it could refer to) is a subset of the references of A or B.  But the references of A and B are equal.  In this sense, the relative clause of C is "restrictive", since it restricts the reference of A.

- A. the location (with no relative clause)
- B. the location, which was called Central Park,
- C. the location which was called Central Park